# How to associate MIME type with a handler in OS X?

Tags: macos, mime-types

How can one add a new MIME type in OS X?

Comment: It's not clear what you're talking about. Add a new MIME type so that what happens exactly?

Comment: So that it's handled by some application, see my answer @DavidSchwartz

Answer (score 9):

The easiest would be to download and install [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/). Go to *System Preferences » Default Apps*, then the *MIME Types* tab.

[image]

Enter your new MIME type in the text box below, press the <kbd>+</kbd> button, and select your handler.

---

Via command line, you need to edit the `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist` preference list. In its array of `LSHandlers`, you need to insert a `Dictionary` containing your new MIME type as:

- `LSHandlerContentTag` – the MIME type
- `LSHandlerContentTagClass`, which is `public.mime-type`
- `LSHandlerRoleAll`, which specifies the Bundle ID of the application that handles it, e.g. `org.videolan.vlc`. You find out the bundle ID by inspecting the `.app` folder and the `Info.plist` preference list therein.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do the same from the command line? Possibly by editing `mime.types`?

Comment: See my updated answer. Are you talking about `apache2/mime.types`? Not sure if you're supposed to edit that. Can you elaborate a bit *why* you need to edit it? What's your context? Without context, it's hard to help you.

Comment: Awesome answer... Wondering if you were aware of which apps might add in this way? I see none in my `LSHandlers` that use this format.... Is that because `LSHandlerContentType` (with values like "public.css" instead of "text/css") is preferred for this? ( https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/9883/206073 seems to suggest such a preference, at least in the case of comparing `LSHandlerContentType` to the "public.filename-extension" `LSHandlerContentTagClass`)

Comment: Latter question now asked at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/328325/preferred-way-to-set-default-application-by-content-mime-type

Comment: @BrettZamir Good question – that's beyond my knowledge. It could also be that the default has been changed in the meantime (my answer is from 2012).

Answer (score 1):

To view `mime-type` of a file in terminal:

```
file --mime-type -b file-name
```