# Run bash command from link in browser

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, osx-yosemite, curl

**Is there a way to run an arbitrary command on OSX by clicking a link in the browser?**

As you know, there are certain types of hyperlinks that launch certain applications with a specified action, for instance:

- Clicking a link opens iTunes and takes you to a view where you can buy a given song or app
- Clicking a magnet link opens your default torrent app and adds it for download

These ask you if you want to allow the action to be performed and whether you want to remeber your choice.

What I'm looking for is to be able to click a link that triggers an action that, in turn, runs:

```
$ curl -fsSL [link for my personal use] | bash
```

This may be by opening `Terminal` or whatever, as long as it runs and I'm able to see the output; however I understand this may not be possible due to security reasons.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I'm far from an expert in these kinds of matters, and don't even have a mac - but often these link triggers are a result of a "MIME" association.  Depending on the control you have on the web page, you may be able to push a unique "Content-Type" header and then configure an associated action in your browser.

Comment: Building on @davidgo's idea:   http://superuser.com/questions/421792/how-to-associate-mime-type-with-a-handler-in-os-x